# Is there a way to scan an entire network range (192.168.0./24) in python and have the data outputted to a text file?

Tags: python-3.x, nmap

I'm relatively new to python so I don't have the most knowledge. I'm using python-nmap to scan the network range but the problem I'm struggling with most is outputting the results to a text file.
This is what I have so far

```
import nmap


ip = '192.168.20.1'
port = 80
nmap = nmap.PortScanner()
result = nmap.scan(ip, str(port))
port_status = (result['scan'][ip]['tcp'][port]['state'])
print(f"Port {port} is {port_status} on {ip}")
with open('nmap.txt','w') as file:
    file.write(f"Port {port} is {port_status} on {ip}")
```

while this works for only a singular ip, im trying to scan for an entire network range, such as 192.168.20.0/24.
When I set to the ip variable to '192.168.20.0/24' I get the following error code:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/john/Desktop/Python/Test.py", line 8, in <module>
    port_status = (result['scan'][ip]['tcp'][port]['state'])
KeyError: '192.168.20.0/24'
```

I feel like there is a very simple fix to this and part of me feels idiotic for posting this but help would be very much appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but `192.168.20.0/24` is `2**24` ca. 16 millions IPs. You need to loop and check each individually.

Comment: Can you try to use `[result['scan'][f"192.168.20.{i}"]["tcp"][port]['state'] for i in range(256)]`? That should check 256 of the IPs

Comment: @Megalng: That's not a general, flexible approach as it only works with `/24` CIDR blocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With CIDR notation you will get multiple results, while your lines 8-11 can only handle a single result. You need a loop to handle your [python-nmap](https://pypi.org/project/python-nmap/) results.

```
import nmap
ips = '192.168.20.0/24'
port = 80
nmap = nmap.PortScanner()
nmap.scan(ips, port)

with open('nmap.txt','w') as file:
    for host in nmap.all_hosts():
        port_state = nmap[host]['tcp'][port]['state']
        print(f"Port {port} is {port_state} on {host}")
        file.write(f"Port {port} is {port_state} on {host}")
```